# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1

Tags: android, cursor

I'm getting the following warning in debugger.  My code consists of Users and their Friends.  At some point in FriendsDAO the username from Users is brought in.  But right now I'm running into a cursor issue below.  Any help is appreciated.

```
05-30 10:32:15.098    1957-1957/com.example.mms.mobile E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.mms.mobile, PID: 1957
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1
        at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getLong(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:74)
        at com.example.mms.mobile.UserDAO.cursorToUser(UserDAO.java:182)
        at com.example.mms.mobile.UserDAO.getUser(UserDAO.java:113)
        at com.example.mms.mobile.FriendsDAO.cursorToFriends(FriendsDAO.java:156)
        at com.example.mms.mobile.FriendsDAO.createFriend(FriendsDAO.java:73)
        at com.example.mms.mobile.AddFriendActivity.onClick(AddFriendActivity.java:120)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

My code for UserDAO and FriendsDAO are below:

```
//UserDAO
public class UserDAO {

public static final String TAG = "UserDAO";

// Database fields
private SQLiteDatabase Database;
private DBHelper DbHelper;
private Context Context;
private String[] AllColumns = {
        DBHelper.USER_ID,
        DBHelper.USER_NAME ,
        DBHelper.PASSWORD ,
        DBHelper.COUNTY ,
        DBHelper.EMAIL ,
        DBHelper.COUNTRY
        };

public UserDAO(Context context) {
    this.Context = context;
    DbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    // open the database
    try {
        open();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "SQLException on opening database " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void open() throws SQLException {
    Database = DbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close() {
    DbHelper.close();
}

public USER createUser(String usrname, String pass, String county, String email,
                       String country) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DBHelper.USER_NAME ,usrname);
    values.put(DBHelper.PASSWORD ,pass);
    values.put(DBHelper.COUNTY ,county);
    values.put(DBHelper.EMAIL ,email);
    values.put(DBHelper.COUNTRY,country);


    long insertId = Database
            .insert(DBHelper.TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);
    Cursor cursor = Database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_LOGIN, AllColumns,
            DBHelper.USER_ID + " = " + insertId, null, null,null,null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    USER newUser = cursorToUser(cursor);
    cursor.close();
    return newUser;
}

public USER getUser(String name) {
    Cursor cursor = Database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_LOGIN, AllColumns,
            DBHelper.USER_NAME + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(name) }, null, null, null);
    //if (cursor != null) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

            USER user = cursorToUser(cursor);

            cursor.moveToNext();

        }

    cursor.close();
    return user;

}

protected USER cursorToUser(Cursor cursor) {
    USER user = new USER();
    user.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
    user.setUser(cursor.getString(1));
    user.setPass(cursor.getString(2));
    user.setCounty(cursor.getString(3));
    user.setEmail(cursor.getString(4));
    user.setCountry(cursor.getString(5));

    return user;
}

}
```

And FriendsDAO:

```
public class FriendDAO {

public static final String TAG = "FriendDAO";

// Database fields
private SQLiteDatabase pDatabase;
private DBHelper pDbHelper;
private Context pContext;
private String[] pAllColumns = {
        DBHelper.FRIEND_ID,
        DBHelper.FRIEND_USERNAME,
        DBHelper.list1_ID,
        DBHelper.list2_ID,
        DBHelper.list3_ID,
        DBHelper.location,
        DBHelper.FRIEND_NAME,
        DBHelper.FRIEND_ADDRESS,
        DBHelper.FRIEND_PHONE_NUMBER
        };

public FriendDAO(Context context) {
    this.pContext = context;
    pDbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    // open the database
    try {
        open();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "SQLException on opening database " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void open() throws SQLException {
    pDatabase = pDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close() {
    pDbHelper.close();
}

public Friend createFriend(String userN, Integer list1ID, Integer list2ID, Integer list3ID,
        String loc, String name, String address, String phone) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DBHelper.FRIEND_USERNAME, userN);
    values.put(DBHelper.list1_ID, list1ID);
    values.put(DBHelper.list2_ID, list2ID);
    values.put(DBHelper.list3_ID, list3ID);
    values.put(DBHelper.location, loc);
    values.put(DBHelper.FRIEND_NAME, name);
    values.put(DBHelper.FRIEND_ADDRESS, address);
    values.put(DBHelper.FRIEND_PHONE_NUMBER, phone);


    long insertId = pDatabase
            .insert(DBHelper.TABLE_FRIENDS, null, values);
    Cursor cursor = pDatabase.query(DBHelper.TABLE_FRIENDS, pAllColumns,
            DBHelper.FRIEND_ID + " = " + insertId, null, null,null,null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Friend newFriend = cursorToFriend(cursor);
    cursor.close();
    return newFriend;
}

protected Friend cursorToFriend(Cursor cursor) {

    Friend friend = new Friend();
    friend.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
    // get The user by id

    String userN = cursor.getString(1);
    UserDAO dao = new UserDAO(pContext);
    USER user = dao.getUser(userN);
    if(user != null)
        friend.setUser(user);
    friend.setlocation(cursor.getString(2));
    friend.setlist1(cursor.getString(3));
    friend.setlist2Id(cursor.getString(4));
    friend.setlist3Id(cursor.getString(5));
    friend.setName(cursor.getString(6));
    friend.setAddress(cursor.getString(7));
    friend.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(8));

    return friend;
}

}
```

Comment: You introduce variable _USER user_ within the while -block. Then return _user_. This is in _getUser_ method. Does this code compile at all i.e is this same code you face the error on?

Comment: Yes, this is the same code I'm getting error on.